# How to generate html documentation with a prefix?

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to generate documentation to put on the web with a certain path prefix. But I can't figure out how to generate the documentation so that the links are absolute instead of relative. The `html_baseurl` parameter doesn't work at all.

Let's say I want to place documentation in the `/docs` prefix when deploying to the production. How can I do that?

Comment: If you learn what is reverse proxy and how to set that up, you will see that you don't need to modify anything on sphinx, but simply create the right reverse proxy rules.

Comment: I want to deploy on GitHub Pages, so I can't adjust a web server's configuration.